# Integrate a library like ShareKit in an AIR app?

Tags: ios, air, libraries

ShareKit is just an example, I need to know if native iOS libraries with UI, can be integrated, linked and used in AIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR has the concept of native applications, but those aren't linked with arbitrary libraries. However, native AIR application can load arbitrary helper applications, and those can use arbitrary libraries. You'll just be on your own in it - no support from AIR, usual native development.

Comment: Thx. Not sure if this question makes sense, but how long would it be to turn a library like shareKit into a native AIR app/library?

Comment: There are no AIR libraries. It's ActionScript libraries, or native libraries. If you go native, you write helper native application, and it uses shareKit or anything directly.

Comment: So, the answer is - how long it takes for you to create native app using shareKit and make it communicate with AIR-based caller (through stdin/stdout, for example.)

Comment: Not sure to understand, you're talking about 2 distinct applications to install on the iOS device (one being made with AIR, and the other one with native tools)? What about "Native extensions" ? ( http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html ).

Comment: Yes, I was talking about (now old-style) architecture with native helper. But native extensions would provide much better interface to native code, although the library needs to be wrapped into AS3 interface, not just linked to AIR app.

Comment: About the "old-style" architecture, does it require that the users install from the appstore 2 distinct apps?

Comment: No, native AIR app just takes some executable with it (packed in AIR package as any resource) and runs it.